# SQL double negation with Not exists

Tags: sql, logic

I have a nested Not Exists, and was wondering if its a double negation. And if I remove both the negation, if it would be the equivalent queries?

```
Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
```

SQL Translation :  "C.Sid for which Does not exist the parts that are not supplied by C.Sid"

```
SELECT C.sid
FROM Catalog C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.pid
                  FROM Parts P
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT C1.sid
                                    FROM Catalog C1
                                    WHERE C1.sid = C.sid
                                    AND C1.pid = P.pid)
                  )
```

Removed Negations : "C.Sid who supply every part"

```
SELECT C.sid
FROM Catalog C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT P.pid
                  FROM Parts P
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT C1.sid
                                    FROM Catalog C1
                                    WHERE C1.sid = C.sid
                                    AND C1.pid = P.pid)
                  )
```

Comment: that will not work, you aren't handling "every part" just "exists a part"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nop, the operations are not equivalent. What you are trying to achieve it's the equivalent to an [algebra division operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29) in SQL.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4f605/1/0) where you might tests the following queries:

The first one:

```
SELECT * FROM Catalog C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.pid FROM Part P
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT C1.sid FROM Catalog C1
                                    WHERE C1.sid = C.sid
                                    AND C1.pid = P.pid) );

sid pid
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
```

The alternative (where you can see that the results are now equivalent):

```
SELECT * FROM Catalog C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT P.pid FROM Part p
              WHERE EXISTS (SELECT C1.sid FROM Catalog C1
                            WHERE C1.sid = C.sid
                              AND C1.pid = P.pid) );

sid pid
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   3
```

And a classical Database course exercise:

```
-- Suppliers for which doesn't exists any part that they doesn't provide.
SELECT * FROM supplier S
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM part P
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM catalog C
                                      WHERE S.sid = C.sid
                                        AND P.pid = C.pid ) );

sid name
1   "Dath Vader"
2   "Han Solo"
```

Dissecting part of the above query might give you a better insight on the logic involved in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM part P
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM catalog C
                   WHERE P.pid = C.pid
                     AND C.sid = 3); -- R2D2 Here!

pid name
2   "Laser Gun"
```

R2D2 was excluded from the result set because it's the only one selling a product not listed in the part table. 
The existence of this row excludes RD2D from the final result set.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is `C.Sid` who supplies a part that is in the catalog.

There is no sense of "all" in the query.  The two queries are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question is just educational or you are asking for a better way to solve your question.

If you know how many parts sell each supplier, and know how many parts are. Is easy to compare those values.

```
SELECT C.Sid
FROM Catalog C
GROUP BY C.Sid
HAVING COUNT(pid) = (SELECT COUNT(P.pid)
                     FROM Parts P)
```